# Loop through each pivot item and highlight entire row based on condition

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

In my project i'm working in i need to highlight certain rows of my pivot table where column `SubstitutionID` has more than one entries to its name.

I've alreay build a function that returns unique `SubstitutionID` and Child count in a dictionary object.

Also, i've done the looping part of my pivot to highlight the pivot items. which works fine but i need to hightlight the entire row contents of pivot table. below code highlights only one cell of my pivot table.

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = ITBuild.GetDuplicateEntries()

Dim pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem
Dim c As Variant, x As Variant

Set pt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").PivotTables(1)
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("SubstitutionID")

For Each x In dict.keys
    If VBA.CInt(dict.Item(x)) > 1 Then
        For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
            If VBA.Trim(pi.Caption) = VBA.Trim(x) Then
                For Each c In pi.DataRange
                    c.Font.Color = vbRed
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

If there any alternate please help me out in this one.

Comment: If `c` represents a single cell then `c.EntireRow` gives you the entire row of that cell `c`.

Comment: Tried that. Sorry i meant wrong -  not the entrire row. the area pivot table covers. it is dynamic vary from 6 to 18 columns.

Comment: You asked the wrong question then: You asked for entire row. Please [edit] and correct your question then. It's unclear what you actually mean but try `c.CurrentRegion` maybe. Otherwise be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate your pivot table's start and end column index and use them corresponding to your `c.Row`.

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = ITBuild.GetDuplicateEntries()

Dim pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem
Dim c As Variant, x As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
Dim sCol As Long, eCol As Long

Set pt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").PivotTables(1)

arr = VBA.Split(pt.TableRange2.Address, ":")
sCol = Range(arr(0)).Column
eCol = Range(arr(1)).Column

Set pf = pt.PivotFields("SubstitutionID")

For Each x In dict.keys
    If VBA.CInt(dict.Item(x)) > 1 Then
        For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
            If VBA.Trim(pi.Caption) = VBA.Trim(x) Then
                For Each c In pi.DataRange
                    Range(Cells(c.Row, sCol), Cells(c.Row, eCol)).Font.Color = vbRed
                    'c.Font.Color = vbRed
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks @nagarajannd - Worked :)